# What does ((void)(identifier)) mean in C?

Tags: c

There's a piece of code that confuses me. I don't know what the effect is. The code is like that:

```c
void set_jemalloc_bg_thread(int enable) {
    ((void)(enable));
}
```

Maybe it's reserved for debug?

Comment: Is it an offering to the compiler gods?

Comment: The purpose is to remove compiler warning for unused parameter `enable`.